# Slow booting / starting after apt-get update 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, updates

I have just bought a new Lenovo Ideapad Z580, which came with Windows 8.

I have since, removed that and installed 12.04 on top. Everything works fine. However, after I have to updated all 272 updates using update manager, my machine now takes about 15mins to get to the password/login page. Once I have logged in everything works fine.

I have a before and after bootchart image if that helps (should I save it online e.g. pastebin, or can I attach it here?). It's very odd, in that the slow image has the opening init command taking over 1000 seconds, before the boot process kicks in.

Since having this issue I have tried multiple things to fix it with no success.

Yesterday however, I did spend the entire day updating 5-10 updates at a time, to see if I could find the culprit for the slow boot. After going through all of them, I managed to get everything installed fine! It worked!! Then I went to install Mate on top, and bang, back to 15 minute boot times. Uninstalling Mate, didn't fix this!

I currently have it working because I removed the latest kernel 3.2.0-35, so now have 3.2.0-29.

I did this by doing

sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic
sudo update-grub2

However, even though it is working now, I know that if I upgrade anything I will be left with the 15 minute boot times again.

Hopefully someone out there can help.

Thanks

Russ

Answer (score 1):

Ideapad Z580 users seem to be experiencing an ACPI issue.  Booting with ACPI=Off works but I have read this cripples hyperthreading (so what is the point?)    Here is a related thread:

[Ideapad Z580 won't boot kernels above 3.2.0-32](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239707/ideapad-z580-wont-boot-kernels-above-3-2-0-32)