# Ideapad Z580 won't boot kernels above 3.2.0-32

Tags: boot, kernel, lenovo, ideapad

I'm running Ubuntu 64 bit 12.04.1 LTS.  I see either a blinking cursor or a black screen if I try to boot all kernels beginning at 3.2.0-33 and later.   *Safe mode* fails for those kernels as well.

However, my system boots fine and runs fine on kernel 3.2.0-32 as well as kernels previous to that.

I have seen other Z580 users with this same problem on other forums.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I'm running 64 bit Lubuntu 12.10 on my Z580 and managed to fix the booting issue using the approach described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1093217/comments/63).

The steps that I followed are:

1. Installed iasl

   ```
   sudo apt-get install iasl
   ```
2. Made a copy of the DSDT file.

   ```
   sudo cp /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/DSDT ~/DSDT
   ```
3. Decompiled the DSDT file to a .dsl file

   ```
   sudo chmod +r DSDT
   iasl -d DSDT
   ```
4. Edited the DSDT.dsl to add a small sleep command in the WAEC method.

   ```
    Method (WAEC, 0, NotSerialized)
   {
       Name (CUNT, 0x1E)
       While (LNotEqual (^PCI0.LPCB.EC0.BYFG, Zero))
       {
           Sleep (0x05)
           Decrement (CUNT)
           If (LEqual (CUNT, Zero))
           {
               Store (Zero, ^PCI0.LPCB.EC0.BYFG)
               Store (Zero, ^PCI0.LPCB.EC0.DRFG)
               Break
           }
       }
       Sleep (50) // #### adding this line is the only change ####
   }
   ```
5. Produced a .aml file from DSDL.dsl

   ```
   iasl DSDT.dsl
   ```
6. Copied to .aml file to the /boot directory

   ```
   mv DSDT.aml dsdt.aml
   sudo cp dsdt.aml /boot/
   ```
7. Added the .aml file to the grub configuration using the method described [here](http://blog.michael.kuron-germany.de/2011/03/patching-dsdt-in-recent-linux-kernels-without-recompiling/). First downloaded the 01_acpi.txt file. Then:

   ```
   mv 01_acpi.txt 01_acpi
   chmod +x 01_acpi
   sudo mv 01_acpi /etc/grub.d
   ```
8. Updated grub configuration

   ```
   sudo update-grub2
   ```
9. Once I rebooted the problems disappeared.

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

My current kernel version is 3.5.0-17-generic. Not sure what happens on newer kernels.

Answer (score 0):

On Z580, kernel 3.2.0-35 boots but it takes 12-13 minutes. `dmesg` shows timeouts and errors in acpi. Booting with `acpi=off` kernel parameter results in faster boot but maybe a less restrictive setting can be found.

Comment: I did not want to disable `acpi` since so much may depend on it.  So for now I am just living with the 13 minute cold boot - otherwise everything appears to work normally.

Comment: This is a consistent problem for Z580 owners.  I have found several related threads:

Comment: Disabling ACPI seems a rather awful solution because I have read that hyperthreading is sacrificed.  We ought to be able to use it.  For now I am running an old kernel and refusing to update. Related threads:  [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2099676) ; [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/234346/slow-booting-starting-after-apt-get-update-12-04) ; [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/248129/lenovo-z580-boots-into-kernel-3-2-0-36-very-slowly)

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu 12.10 amd64 and had same problem.

I updated to kernel version 3.8.1 with following howto http://www.adminlife.net/howtos/linux-kernel-backen-the-debian-way/

Now the laptop starts without problems and ACPI support.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hi, I would like to tell everyone that, out of curiosity, I compiled and installed kernel 3.8.1 too.   This kernel boots *sometimes*, but never twice in a row.  When it boots there are no problems with acpi!!   But more than 50% of the time it has the same long lag (> 10 min) or non-boot (in all cases, just a black screen) as kernels 3.2.0-33 through 3.2.0-38 (the last one I have tried).  So, clearly the 3.8.1 kernel is *capable* of functioning fine, but I am totally unclear as to why it more often does not boot.

Comment: Confirming that kernel 3.8.1 doesn't resolve the problem. A fix has been submitted, but it requires hacking DSDT for the time being: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1093217/comments/63

Comment: Hello, a very belated follow up.   I confirm that the fix posted by user pushka works for me (see link he has posted, March 27).  Boot delays are fixed.  Thank you, very, very much.

Comment: Glad it worked. Out of interest, did you get any warnings when you recompiled DSDT? I got some 'Unknown reserved name' warnings so didn't go any further. Maybe they are just trivial...

Comment: I suppose it makes sense we'd get the same warnings with the same hardware situation.  Yes, the iasl compiler produced 20 "remarks" and 3 warnings about that 'Unknown reserved name' (_CFG).  Hopefully they are just trivial!  I cannot emphasize how much of a relief it is to boot normally.